# INDEX MATCH with Two Criteria - Error w/ Cell Autofill

Tags: excel

I am working on a hiring trends report and have an Excel table with multiple entries per ID/individual (as several individuals have left and been rehired over years). The table looks something like this:

```
WORKSHEET: SHEET1
A       B           C              D
ID      Name        Location       Hire Date
1122    Karen       Chicago        01/01/2018
1038    Tom         Chicago        05/22/2016
2845    Angel       Pittsburgh     11/15/2016
1122    Karen       New York       10/08/2013
4992    Mallory     Seattle        09/14/2015
2845    Angel       Pittsburgh     07/21/2011
1122    Karen       Pittsburgh     08/22/2011
```

I have created a new table with only one entry per person and their most recent hire date. The next step is to populate the table with location data based on the person's ID ***and*** specified hire date.

My approach was to use an INDEX-MATCH expression with two match statements (one for ID and one for hire date):

```
=INDEX('SHEET1'!$C$2:$C$2000,
MATCH('SHEET2'!A2,'SHEET1'!$A$2:$A$2000,0),
MATCH('SHEET2'!D2,'SHEET1'!$D$2:$D$2000,0))
```

The first row where I enter the expression retrieves the correct location data. However, when I attempt to populate the remaining rows in that column, I get a #REF! error, as illustrated below.

```
WORKSHEET: SHEET2
A       B           C              D
ID      Name        Location       Hire Date
1122    Karen       Chicago        01/01/2018
1038    Tom         #REF!          05/22/2016
2845    Angel       #REF!          11/15/2016
4992    Mallory     #REF!          09/14/2015
```

I've tested each INDEX-MATCH expression separately (first testing for a match only on ID and then testing for a match only on hire date). Each one works separately, and as shown above, it does work for the first row--it just will not autofill for other rows. I've also checked SHEET1 and each individual definitely has the correct matching criteria on SHEET2 for referencing.

Can anyone help with either suggesting a way to fix my expression or an alternative way to retrieve the location data based on two criteria? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument to INDEX is the column number, which is why you get a #REF error. You can use LOOKUP instead:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/('SHEET2'!A2='SHEET1'!$A$2:$A$2000)/('SHEET2'!D2='SHEET1'!$D$2:$D$2000),'SHEET1'!$C$2:$C$2000)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! This worked beautifully and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this formula :

`=INDEX(Sheet1!C1:C2000;MATCH(1;INDEX((Sheet1!A1:A2000=Sheet2!A1)*(Sheet1!D1:D2000=Sheet2!D1);0;1);0))`

so you can use more than one criteria in secend index like this:

`=INDEX((criteria1)*(criteria2)*(criteria3);)`